# Why the 3d Lorenz attractor has a butterfly shape? Why isn't it 3 dimensional too?

Tags: chaos-theory, complex-systems

The [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) has a butterfly shaped a strange attractor, but we plot it in 3D. Why is not it has a 3D shape too? It has a strange shape? It is a non-integer dimensional attractor.

Comment: Here's an [interactive version](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/6f060da8f837cf124082cc5e0c288a89) of the Python code from that Wikipedia page, which makes the 3D structure a bit easier to see. Click the `Live demo` link in the comment at the bottom of the page to see the plot in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do in 3d the Lorenz attractor has a butterfly shape?

Without dwelling on the why/how discussion, if you want to go deep on the "why", you might want to check [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007%2FBF02684769) ([e-print](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1979__50__59_0/)).

On a more superficial take, the two unstable fixed points at the centers of the wings and their invariant manifolds are central for describing what's going on: Typical orbits spiral around a wing center, are eventually kicked out of it, since the equilibrium is unstable, and switch to spiraling around the other wing center and the process then repeats ad infinitum; these spirals happen to not be coplanar, but to meet at an angle, resembling partially open butterfly wings; lastly, since a flow in 2D is regular, the chaotic flow has to take place in a dimension greater than 2, i.e., have some thickness. This description is little more than simply narrating what can be seen in the Lorenz attractor Wikipedia animation, but is supported by a proper stability analysis.

> Why isn't it 3 dimensional too?

For typical chaotic parameter values (see figure below, from [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.29.2928)) the system's 3 Lyapunov exponents are: $\lambda_0=0$, in the flow direction;  $\lambda_+>0$, measuring its chaoticity; and a dominant $\lambda_-<0$, which prevents the system from exploding and, since $|\lambda_-|>\lambda_+$, squashes the attractor in its famous almost 2D shape. This is best seen using the [Kaplan–Yorke formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Yorke_conjecture) for the attractor's fractal dimension $D$ (see also [Lyapunov dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_dimension)):

$$
D = 2 + \frac{\lambda_+}{|\lambda_-|},
$$
resulting, for typical parameter values, in $D=2.06\pm0.01$.

It's worth mentioning that, since it "doesn't fit" in 2D, popularly one might say *it is* 3D, but this could be misleading.

[image]

> but we plot it in 3D

The system's phase space is 3D, as it's described by three variables. Besides, when the attractor has a dimension larger than 2, it makes sense to visualize it placed in three dimensions (or, if we want to be pedantic, we most often use 2D projections of it).

> It has a strange shape? It is a non-integer dimensional attractor.

Yes, by definition: Since it's a fractal attractor, it's called "[strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor)".

Comment: Is there any other reason why this?  When I told my professor the reason might be lyapunov exponentials, she told me this is not the reason.

Comment: @zannah I've added a paragraph, is that what you're looking for?